# Asset instantiation woes

Tags: smart-contract, asset

if I declare an asset:

```
asset a(10, symbol("TST", 0);
```

and I print it:

```
a.print();
```

I get pretty much what I'd expect:

> 10. TST

the format's not quite right (`10 TST` would have been better), but ok. but if the symbol uses 2 decimal digits:

```
asset a(10, symbol("TST", 2));
```

the output I now get is:

> 0.10 TST

WTF??

to add insult to injury, if I pass it from the command line it works just fine:

```
void eosio::test(asset a)
{
    a.print();
}
```

called from the command line like this:

```
cleos push action t test '["10 TST"]' -p t@active
```

I get the expected:

> 10. TST

what is going on here? how am I supposed to initialise my assets when the value I give them changes depending on the precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asset must be expressed in terms of an integer, even if the asset itself will have decimal points.

Therefore `asset a(1, symbol("EOS", 4));` refers to the smallest possible positive amount of EOS you could have (because 1 is the smallest integer larger than zero).

Given that you have 4 decimal places, this corresponds to `0.0001 EOS`.

If you want to express everything how you would expect, then you could do something like this:

```
#define PRECISION 2
asset a(500*pow(10,PRECISION), symbol("TST", PRECISION));
```

This would always return 500 TST, regardless of what you set the precision to.

Comment: my gosh.  I don't know who designed this asset class but it's abhorrent.  so unfriendly.  I would take the time to rewrite it, if I felt I had any hope of having it adopted. but thank you for clarifying that!

Comment: it also means that cleos does a bit of magic for me, instead of passing it through to the class

Answer (score 1):

EOS use int64_t to represent the amount, so there is no decimal. In order to represent the precision, the symbol type has a precision represent the decimal.

eg:

```
asset a(10, symbol("TST", 0);
```

means amount 10, precision 0(the symbol specify the precision is 0), so it will be

> 10. TST

```
asset a(10, symbol("TST", 2));
```

means amount 10, precision 2，so it will be

> 0.10 TST

in cleos way

```
cleos push action t test '["10 TST"]' -p t@active
```

means amount 10, precision 0, so it will be

> 10. TST

```
cleos push action t test '["10.000 TST"]' -p t@active
```

means amount 10000, precision 3, so it will be

> 10.000 TST

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.  it's an absolutely retarded way to do things.  if I write 10, I mean 10, not 0.1 or 0.001 or any other such thing.  I swear to god I should just rewrite the asset class.  it's garbage